# Difference in AMP and MPD between two aircrafts

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Can two aircrafts such as the A320 and A330 have the same Maintenance Planning Document but different Aircraft Maintenance Program?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between Maintenance planning document(MPD) and Maintenance Manual (AMM)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/93180/19)

Comment: Do A320 and A330 have the same MPD? I don't think so